# From MySQL to Mongo data export: how to preserve creation date?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I'm trying to export a MySQL table data to MongoDB, creating a set of "Create" statements in Rails.

My issue is this: in my original table I have "created_at" and "updated_at" fields and I would like to keep the original values even when I export the data to my new MongoDB document.  But after I create a new row in Mongo, even if I tell it to set "created_at" = [my original date], Mongo sets it to the current datetime.

How can I avoid this?  This is my MongoMapper model:

```
class MongoFeedEvent
   include MongoMapper::Document

   key :event_type, String
   key :type_id, Integer
   key :data, String
   timestamps!

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably better off dumping your MySQL table as JSON and then using [`mongoimport`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongoimport) to import that JSON; this will be a lot faster than doing it row by row through MongoMapper and it will bypass your problem completely as a happy side effect.

There's a gem that will help you dump your MySQL database to JSON called [mysql2xxxx](https://github.com/seamusabshere/mysql2xxxx):

> [How to export a MySQL database to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036605/how-to-export-a-mysql-database-to-json/5327369#5327369)

I haven't used it but the author seems to hang out on SO so you should be able to get help with it if necessary. Or, write a quick one-off script to dump your data to JSON.

Once you have your JSON, you can import it with `mongoimport` and move on to more interesting problems.

Also, `mongoimport` understands CSV and [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) can write CSV directly:

> The `mysqldump` command can also generate output in CSV, other delimited text, or XML format.

So skip MongoMapper and row-by-row copying completely for the data transfer. Dump your data to CSV or JSON and then import that all at once.