# JSON output of a MySQL query is not displaying data when it is over 1026 bytes

Tags: mysql, json

I am using the following query to get JSON format data :

```
     SELECT 
          CONCAT("[",
              GROUP_CONCAT(
                 CONCAT("{""latitude"":""",Latitude,""""),
                 CONCAT(",""londitude"":""",Longitude),"""}") 
          ,"]") AS json 
     FROM hq6k2_devicedata_861001000468427  
     where ReceiveTime between '2014-08-31 14:34:19' and '2014-08-31 14:40:36';
```

What I have observed, this query works perfectly when the return output size is below ~1026 bytes. But when it is exceeding that range the output is like following :

```
[
    {
        "latitude": "2344.152860N",
        "londitude": "09024.699120E"
    },
    {
        "latitude": "2344.152860N",
        "londitude": "09024.699120E"
    },
//Other data and finally the last one :
    {
        "latitude": "234] //Closing the JSON with incomplete data
```

Am I missing something or there is any size limit for this kind of query ?

Comment: Here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036605/how-to-export-a-mysql-database-to-json

Comment: No, I haven't tried that in programming yet. Yes, I run this query directly at terminal. I am using java in backend, and I know how to make json data in java. No issue with that. My concern is , whats wrong with my this attempt to generate json data from direct mysql query in terminal

Comment: See that post i linked to, it explains exactly the same problem and its solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` in a MySQL query to convert multiple rows into a single string. However, the maximum length of the result of this function is 1024 characters.

You can change the param group_concat_max_len to increase this limit:

`SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;`

Above is set for SESSION

`SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1000000;`

above is set for GLOBAL

Please check below link for more details :
[http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat](https://web.archive.org/web/20160506092209/http://dev.mysql.com:80/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Great that resolved your problem. @Nazar-E-Bukhari :)