# retrieve json data from mysql and get value as object

Tags: php

I have two table in my database (meta_key, meta_value) and I am using the below code to get value from database

```
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select * FROM tablename where meta_key='websiteurl' or meta_key='profile_photo'");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
   $output[]=$row;
```

the above code retreive the data like this

```
    meta_key    "profile_photo"
    meta_value  "profile_photo.jpg"
    meta_key    "websiteurl"
    meta_value  "sample.com"
```

I want to get data like this

```
profile_photo   "profile_photo.jpg"
websiteurl  "sample.com"
```

How to do that. thank

Comment: can you show the output of `var_dump($row);` put it inside while and show us the output. Also are you using wordpress?

Comment: BTW, that's not JSON.

Comment: This topic is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036605/how-to-export-a-mysql-database-to-json

Comment: Is the question about receiving the data as an object or about formatting the output?

Answer (score 0):

Make an associative array:

```
$output[$row['meta_key']] = $row['meta_value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
  $output[$row['meta_key']] = $row['meta_value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use correct function.

In your case you use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` that returns associative array

All you need is to use function `mysqli_fetch_object()` that returns an object.

PHP Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope it will work

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
  $output[] = [$row['meta_key']=>$row['meta_value']];
}
```